# Print multiple pages with a single command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, printing

I need to print multiple pages of multiple users (4 pages each for 2000 users, 8000 pages in total) with a single print command in Rails. These pages are basically application forms for each user.

I already setup required print pages and css needed. And I can print each application form individually. But I need to do this for all applicants, which can be as much as 2000 in 1 go.

I've tried to use `pdfkit` to get pdfs for all applications, but `wkhtmltopdf` installation is problematic on the deployment server.

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: How do I able to print those pages with a single command?